# Remote method in LoopBack not being called

Tags: javascript, rest, loopbackjs

When calling a remote method in my LoopBack project, it seems to only return an empty array. I don't think it is really being called at all but perhaps the default implementation is being called.

**member.js**

```
module.exports = function(Member) {
  Member.getProjectsForMember = function(id, callback) {
    console.error('HERE');
    return callback(null, {'test': '123'});
  };
};
```

**member.json**

```
{
  "name": "member",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "projects": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "project",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": false
      }
    }
  },
  "acls": [{
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {
    "getProjectsForMember": {
      "accepts": [{
        "arg": "id",
        "type": "number",
        "required": true,
        "http": {
          "source": "path"
        }
      }],
      "returns": [{
        "arg": "projects",
        "type": "Object",
        "root": true,
      }],
      "http": [{
        "path": "/:id/projects",
        "verb": "get"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I am calling it using the LoopBack API Explorer via a GET to */members/{id}/projects*:
`http://localhost:3000/api/members/3e26u0aa62155715vcb52afa/projects?access_token=R6GKVHwFuMG2caJexuyoMd0JSNOWtvLVXIEmRj1IkNSrM54bwomQLxHcpqlyFaHk`

The response is `[]`. I would expect to see the response of `{'test': '123'}` and the 'HERE' logged to the terminal but I do not.

Comment: That code works correctly for me. Did you add method name to model-config.json? (I guess that yes, because without this it is impossible to make request to "/:id/projects" endpoint.)

Comment: I did add the model name (not the method name) to model-config.json. I have found that this works only if I remove the relation definition from member.json...